# Line in polar coordinates

Tags: trigonometry, polar-coordinates

I just wanted to clarify something. A line in polar coordinates has the parameterization of $\theta = k\pi$ for $k \in \mathbb{R}$ right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Those would be lines through the origin (in which case, you don't even need the $\pi$). How would you write the equation of a line that doesn't go through the origin, like $x=2$ ? Calling it a parametrization would also be a mistake - we haven't parametrized anything since $k$ must be a constant value for any given line.

Comment: @NinadMunshi $r=2\sec(\theta)$

Comment: @Graviton haha thank you, but I did mean for OP to answer that

Comment: For lines not through the origin polar coordinates are not very useful.

Comment: O sorry, for not clarifying but mean a line through the origin.

Comment: @JCAA How can you be so categorical ? This isn't true. In the framework of image processing, I have had several times to use the equation given in the answer by marwalix, in particular for lines obtained through the inversion of circles passing through the origin.

Comment: i know very little about image processing. But the polar equation of a line not passing through the origin looks to me more complicated than $ y=kx+b$. I agree that the polar equation appears naturally sometimes (e.g., in hyperbolic geometry and with Moebius transformations, as you mention).

Answer (score 2):

The line described by your polar equation goes through the origin and is at a constant angle from the $x$ axis.

Now for a line perpendicular to a radial line making a constant angle $\phi$ with the $x$ axis, at a distance $r_0\neq 0$ from the origin, the general polar equation is

$$r(\theta)={r_0\over \cos(\theta-\phi)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $x = r \cos \theta$ and $y= r \sin \theta$ and see if you can find the polar equations for

$$y = mx + b \\ y = x + b \\ y = x$$  For the third equation, what do you notice?

Answer (score 0):

$\theta=k\pi,k\in\mathbb R$ is just $\theta\in\mathbb R$.

This describes the locus of points at any distance from the origin, in the direction of $\theta$. Hence it is a half-line from the origin, possibly not what you want.

---

A line of Cartesian equation

$$ax+by+c=0$$ becomes

$$ar\cos\theta+br\sin\theta+c=0$$ or

$$r=-\frac c{a\cos\theta+b\sin\theta}.$$

Answer (score 0):

If follows from polar coordinate definition

$$ \theta = constant = c$$

is a line in polar coordinates through the origin. In particular

$$c= 0,  k\pi,\quad k \in \mathbb{R}$$
are lines along x-axis
and
$$c= 1,  \pi(2k-1) $$

are lines along y-axis.