# How to convert a line from Cartesian to Polar form?

Tags: geometry, polar-coordinates

I have two points on a $x, y$ axis represented as $P_1(x_1, y_1)$ and $P_2(x_2, y_2)$ for which a line can be computed in Cartesian form $y=mx+b$ with parameters $(m,b)$. I want to be able to represent the same line on Polar coordinate system with parameters $(r,θ)$.

What is the formula to compute the values for $r$ and $θ$ of the line passing points $P_1$ and $P_2$ (or a line represented as $y=mx+b$)?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3794791

Answer (score 1):

You know:

$$x=\rho\cos(\theta)$$
$$y=\rho\sin(\theta)$$
To find $m$ and $b$ you get the system:
$$y_1=mx_1+b$$
$$y_2=mx_2+b$$
So you find $m$ and $b$.
The equation in polar coordinates is then:
$$\rho\sin(\theta)=m\rho\cos(\theta)+b$$

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's definitely my limited understanding, but I need to actually compute the $θ$ and $ρ$ values for that given line represented as $y=mx+b$. How do I do that? 

Above gives me the function in Polar coordinates. 

For context, I want to transfrom the outputs of [OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/db0/tutorial_hough_lines.html) `cv2.HoughLinesP` (line defined by two points) to `cv2.HoughLines` format (line defined by values of $ρ$ and $θ$).

Comment: You have to calculate $b$ and $m$. After this, you have the equation of the line in terms of $\rho$ and $\theta$. You can get the values of $m$ and $b$ from the system in which there are the values of $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2$